# save a range of data from temp worksheet to another workbook in directory

Tags: excel, vba

i have a worksheet "Disso" in workbook 1 and  another worksheet "Sheet1" in workbook 2. I need to copy data from Workbook 1 "Disso" column A to H. Then Open directory go to Workbook 2  "Sheet1" and find the last row from column A to H and paste the data. After pasting the data i want the worksheet "Disso" to be deleted from the workbook.
I am stuck and i really need help.

```
Set Sheet = Worksheets("Disso") 
lastrow = Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
Sheet.Range("A2:H" & lastrow).Copy 
wb.Open "C:\Users\harry\Desktop\STO Update\LDG\Workbook 2.xlsm" 
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste 
wb.Save
wb.Close 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Sheet.delete 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Remove the `For Each...Next` loop block (you're not really iterating all sheets, you're just looking for one in particular, right?), and do `Set Sheet = Worksheets("Disso")`; then `Sheet.Copy ...` instead of `Worksheets("Disso").Copy ...`, and then `Sheet.Delete`.

Comment: Subscript out of range.  Worksheets("Disso").Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon editted the code but im still not getting what i want.

Comment: Subscript out of range at `Set Sheet = Worksheets("Disso")`? Does the active workbook contain a sheet whose name is "Disso"?

Comment: yes it does. @MathieuGuindon. I have posted the edited code above. take a look and see if you do anything to make it work.

Comment: If the "Disso" sheet is in `ThisWorkbook` (the file with the VBA code)? If so try `Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Disso")`, or set its `(Name)` property (F4) to e.g. `DissoSheet` and then you can use `DissoSheet` to refer to that specific sheet, without needing to dereference it from a `Worksheets` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define the first empty cell in the destination worksheet. Also properly identifying and assigning your variables, and indenting your code is important.

```
'Define your variables
Dim sorcews As Worksheet, destwb As Workbook, destws As Worksheet

'Assign your variables
Set sorcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Assign the workbook you open to a variable
Set destwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\harry\Desktop\STO Update\LDG\Workbook 2.xlsm")
Set destws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'This section copies the range from your source ws and paste to your destination ws
    sorcews.Range("A2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
    Destination:=destws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    destwb.Save
    destwb.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    scorcews.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```